# how to set value in object using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

could you please tell me how to set value in object property using xslt?

i try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <script type="text/javascript">
         <![CDATA[
       var obj ={
        a:"mm",
        catalog:<xsl:value-of select="catalog"/>
        }
         ]]>
    </script>
    <xsl:value-of select="catalog"/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:transform>

http://xsltransform.net/6rewNyu
```

i want to create a object where i want to set its value in `catalog`  property

why it is not working ?

```
catalog:<xsl:value-of select="catalog"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put XSLT code you want to execute into a CDATA section, so simply use

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var obj ={
    a:"mm",
    catalog: '<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(catalog)"/>'
    }

</script>
```

if you want to generate Javascript code where part of the code is computed by XSLT.